# The comment slash // is indented too left (Rider)

Tags: c#, rider

I'm using Rider, and when I comment out a line using the keymap "Comment/uncomment with Line Comment", the slash // is indented too far left and not where the actual word was appearing. Perhaps a picture can illustrate it better.[image]

I'd like the slash to be where the line started originally, like when you use vscode or sublimetext:

[image]

Sorry for the weird topic, but it has been nagging me for quite a while now and can't stop thinking about it while typing (:D). I couldn't find the setting that would change this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check here for how to change it.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Coding_Assistance__Comment_Uncomment_Code.html#commenting-and-uncommenting-with-line-comments

> According to the **Don't indent comments started at first column** option, the comment will be added with or without the indent. You can configure this option for different languages separately, for example, for C# it is on the **Editor | Code Style | C# | Tabs, Indents, Alignment** page of JetBrains Rider settings <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+S</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

`Settings > Editor > Code Style > C# > Tabs, Indents, Alignment:`

And toggle checkbox: `Don't indent comments started at first column.`

[image]